# Stage "dev already exists" for AWS Serverless API with Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-serverless

I need customize [default Stage generated](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-specification-generated-resources-api.html) by AWS::Serverless::Api.

The stack creation is getting error "**dev already exists**".

My template code:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Resources:
  MyApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      Name: my-service
      StageName: dev

  MyApiDeployment:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref MyApi
      StageName: dev

  MyStage:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Stage
    DependsOn: MyApiDeployment
    Properties:
      StageName: dev
      RestApiId: !Ref MyApi
      DeploymentId: !Ref MyApiDeployment

  LambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: MyAssembly::MyNamespace::MyHandler
      Runtime: dotnetcore2.1
      Events:
        ApiRoot:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref MyApi
            Path: /
            Method: ANY
```

Outputs the error:

```
MyStage                                  CREATE_FAILED                            dev already exists
```

The goal is to make reference to Stage from another resource in the same template file.

```
  MyMapping:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::BasePathMapping
    Properties:
      BasePath: my-path
      RestApiId: !Ref MyApi
      Stage: !Ref MyStage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution on this forum: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/issues/192#issuecomment-520893111

The reference in the **Stage property** must be with `!Ref MyApi.Stage`, and **not** with name by string.

Correct code:

```
  MyMapping:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::BasePathMapping
    Properties:
      BasePath: my-path
      RestApiId: !Ref MyApi
      Stage: !Ref MyApi.Stage
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is occurring because you are trying to create the **same resource twice**. By specifying the stage name on the AWS::Serverless::Api resource [**MyApi**] you are creating that stage.

As [per the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-api.html#sam-api-stagename), stage does not have to be specified for API Gateway; however does for SAM. Try removing your stage resource [**MyStage**] and redeploying.

```
Resources:
  MyApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      Name: my-service
      StageName: dev

  MyStage:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Stage
    DependsOn: MyApiDeployment
    Properties:
      StageName: dev
      RestApiId: !Ref MyApi
      DeploymentId: !Ref MyApiDeployment
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to refer to this Stage in another resource in the same template. How to refer to the Stage implicitly created?

Comment: Easy, create a parameter and make both the api resource stagename and apigateway basemapping ref that parameter. In your example all the !Ref stagename does is reference the logical name anyway. e.g. !Ref MyStage == dev

Comment: It worked, very thanks! Both **StageName** and **Stage** receive the external string value as a parameter in the **dotnet lambda deploy-serverless --template-parameters** command line.

Comment: In some cases the error still happened, It seems that **StageName** and **Stage** are not the same type.

Comment: Did you actually do an output value to check why / what the different difference, by all accounts it should be the same thing unless your changing your stage with deployments.